# Can Canadian air travellers still catch a connecting flight home with new on-arrival COVID tests? (Dec 2021)

Tags: air-travel, canada, covid-19

In response to the emerging [omicron variant](https://www.who.int/news/item/26-11-2021-classification-of-omicron-(b.1.1.529)-sars-cov-2-variant-of-concern) of COVID-19, Canada [recently announced](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/trudeau-omicron-more-to-do-1.6267817) that incoming air travellers will be required to take a COVID-19 test on arrival and then self-isolate until they receive results of the test.

What does this mean for fully-vaccinated Canadian citizens returning from non-restricted countries (eg. Mexico) if they reside in smaller towns without an international airport? Will they be blocked from going home via a same-day connecting flight because of mandatory self-isolation upon arrival?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.